How do you determine the basis of a crystal structure?

Consider this Cuprite unit cell like in the picture. I am first thinking that this is a body centered cubic cell, with the atom in the center and the surrounding copper atoms as the basis, hence five atoms in the basis by the looks of it. However the correct answer suggests two oxygen atoms in the basis. The relative coordinates for the oxygen atoms are also very confusing. Isn't the central oxygen just (0.5,0.5,0.5)? How can it be (1,1,1) and then the surrounding copper atoms make sense, like (0.25,0.25,0.25) etc... How can the central oxygen atom be (1,1,1) if it is (0.25,0.25,0.25) units away from one of the corner Copper atoms? And why is there two oxygen atoms in the basis? Is there a rule on how to determine this? I am struggling with any type of "find the coordinates" or "how many atoms is in the primitive or unit cell". Kittel is not explaining this anywhere either.

This is homework-like. However, I can help.
If there is any atom purely inside the cell, you count it fully.
If there is any atom on a face of the cell, you count it half.
You have 8 corners of this cube, so the oxygen there contribute an eighth each---that means once.
Hence two oxygen only in this cell. This is thus Cu${}_2$O
There is a relation, (x+1,y,z)=(x,y,z) so (1,1,1)=(0,0,0) and (1.5,1.5,1.5)=(0.5,0.5,0.5).

This brings the problem down to getting the Cu positioned correctly.
One easy way is to consider it as
(+0.25,+0.25,+0.25) and (-0.25,-0.25,+0.25), the latter of which turns into (0.75,0.75,0.25)
The other pair are (+0.25,-0.25,-0.25) and (-0.25,+0.25,-0.25), and viola, you see that there is only one answer in the given choices is correct.
